# obscure jquery syntax in supersized slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was going through the supersized.3.2.5.js file of the full screen image slider - [supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/).

I can't understand the syntax of the following lines. Though I am not pasting the complete code here yet i think that is not any prob for the syntax explanation.

```
/* Variables
        ----------------------------*/
            var el = '#supersized',
            base = this;
        // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el;
```

I need the explanation of the last 2 lines ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just save the jQuery object and the id string in different variables

The jQuery one gets prefixed with $

base.$el = jQuery Object version of el (#supersized)

base.el == just the id (the string)

Comment: base.$el and base.el - what do they mean? what syntax here? what is the difference?

Comment: $ is a character you can use in javascript variables, it has the same purpose as all other characters you can use for a variable. In JS it doesn't matter if you call your variables $myVar, myVar or even my$Var

Comment: are $el and el same or not? base= this. then what do base.$el and base.el mean?

Comment: They are not. el and $el are two different variables, or better, properties of base. $el contains the jQuery object, el contains the string for the ID. People tend to prefix variables that contain jQuery objects with $. Please do me a favor and read my explanations slowly, I already gave you this answer

Comment: ok, nice. why base.$el i.e. this.el? Couldn't it be only $el?

Comment: Probably not because this way el and $el are appended to an object in the current context, which means that other functions/callbacks/procedures working with this object can access these properties again if needed

Answer (score 0):

The penultimate line is storing a jQuery object containing the DOM element with ID 'supersized', while the last line is storing the selector string '#supersized' only.

Comment: base.$el and base.el - what do they mean? what syntax here? what is the difference?

Comment: may i ask u to make a visit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952988/adding-html-text-to-supersized-jquery-image-slide/8178936#comment10048045_8178936