# adding text on each page of Supersized 3.2 – Fullscreen Slideshow jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slide, supersized

I'm looking for an answer in regards of Supersized Slideshow Jquery. I want to add each HTML/TEXT on the each slide. (i.E - if there are 4 pages, 4 separate texts will be embeded on each slide. )

I know there was a discussion before "adding html text to supersized jquery image slider.

Re: adding html text to supersized jquery image slide
[adding html text to supersized jquery image slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952988/adding-html-text-to-supersized-jquery-image-slide)

I followed the direction but I do not understand creating 'php' page and "put a blank div #brief_holder in the same page of slide." part. Also, I'm curious this code is really working...

Is there anybody who solved this problem and got some answer for me...?

Thanks so much for your kindness and I look forward to hearing from you.

Best,
Bonnie

Comment: Could you provide the code where you create your slideshow please?

Comment: @user3381913 Would the text be different for each image?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough example so you get an idea how to do this. Sorry I couldn't get fsfiddle to work well with supersized, so goto http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/slide.html and paste the code below into the chrome dev console. When implementing, this shoud should run after supersized is loaded.

```
var slide_text_array = [ 'slide 1 text', 'slide 2 text', 'slide 3 text', 'slide 4 text', 'slide 5 text', 'slide 6 text', 'slide 7 text', 'slide 8 text', 'slide 9 text', 'slide 10 text' ];

$('#supersized li a img').each( function(i,slide_img){ //get each loaded slide
    $(slide_img).css('z-index', '100');//to make the image appear behind the text
    var slide_a = $(slide_img).parent()
    $(slide_a).prepend('<h1 style="font-size: 100px; z-index: 200; position: absolute;">'+ slide_text_array[i] +'</h1>'); //insert text
});
```

Rather than looping though all slides after supersized load, you can add text before each slide starts. Have a look at http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#theme-before but this should get you going. If you are still having issues, try to setup a jsfiddle.net or codepen example so we can edit it for you. Good luck!

[image]